# esp8266 V0.9 not compatible with SD.h

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to attach a SD card to my esp8266 V0.9 module to save and read files, but when I use the SD.h library when coding in de Arduino environment it gives the following error:

```
  #error Architecture or board not supported.
```

Is there a way to solve this? It also gives this error when I try to compile/run an example provided by Arduino.

Comment: This seens to be a compile error (with SD.h), correct?  SUGGESTIONS: look here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3061 and here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=429626.0; make sure you download the latest version.

Comment: i had to fork and rename the `File()` class `File2()` to avoid a conflict with the SPIFFS `File` (iirc). looks like the [newest version](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/SD) might be ok

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by including the SdFat.h library and adding the line 'SdFat SD;. By doing this, the examples worked.